# how to take values of javascript variable in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

I developed a work for my university and I have a problem:
My code:

```
    markers.push({
    coords: 
          { lat: parseFloat(datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 1].toString()), 
           lng: parseFloat(datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 2].toString())},
    content:
    "Id de incidencia: " + datosIncidencia[(7 * i)].toString()
    + '\n' +  "Descripcion: " + datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 3] + 
    + '\n' +  "Fecha Problema: " + datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 4] + '\n' +

    '<img src = "data:image/gif;base64, datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 
    6].toString()">');
```

In the last 2 lines I have my problem:
the variable `datosIncidencia` is an array of strings (obviously I work in javascript so is *var*, but it contains strings).
In the position `[(7 * i) + 6]` it has a string base64 (its a type of image extension), but its code take the vairable like a string.
For example, if `datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 6]=abcde`, I want that the program take:

```
    <img src = "data:image/gif;base64, abcde">
```

but it takes:

```
    <img src = "data:image/gif;base64, datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 
    6].toString()">
```

and obviously, it cant be find the image.

For finish, I have to say that this code is correct:
If I put the string base64 directly in the position, I can see the image in the web page.

Thanks for all

Comment: JS template literals might make your life easier: `\`<img src="data:image/gif;base64, ${datosIncidencia[(7*i)+6].toString()}">\``. Or you know, do what you did and separate that with `+`: `'<img src = "data:image/gif;base64, ' + datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 
6].toString() + '">'`. Or perhaps you should clarify more about your problem.

Comment: The question here is basically "How do I concat two strings in javascript". Look at how `datosIncidencia` is used before the line you have a question about.. Do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you code says to do that!

```
'<img src = "data:image/gif;base64, ' + datosIncidencia[(7 * i) + 
6].toString() + '">');
```

Is probably what you meant.

Comment: You may mark this as the answer of your question if it was useful.